# Google Cloud Functions: Could not authenticate request

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am using a node.js function on Google Cloud Functions to save Pub/Sub messages to GCS (Storage), but it randomly gives me the following error for some messages (most of the messages are succesfully written):

`"Error: Could not authenticate request. Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information."`

It doesn't make sense, once running on GCE would use same service-account for all messages, which has the proper permissions, and all messages comes from the same source and goes to the same destination. Can someone enlighten me on what could I do?

I'm using google-cloud/storage version 0.8.0.

```
/**
 * Triggered from a message on a Cloud Pub/Sub topic.
 *
 * @param {!Object} event The Cloud Functions event.
 * @param {!Function} The callback function.
 */

const bucketName = 'backup-queue-bucket';

const util = require('util')
const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')();
const crypto = require('crypto');

exports.backupQueue = function backupQueue(event, callback) {
    // The Cloud Pub/Sub Message object.
    const timestamp = event.timestamp;
    const resources = event.resource.split('/');
    const pubsubMessage = event.data;
    const messageContent = Buffer.from(pubsubMessage.data, 'base64').toString();

    // We're just going to log the message to prove that
    // it worked.      
      var queueName = resources[resources.length-1];
    console.log(`Message received: ${messageContent} in queue ${queueName}`);

    const filename = timestamp+'_'+crypto.createHash('md5').update(messageContent).digest('hex');

    const bucket = gcs.bucket(bucketName);
    const file = bucket.file(queueName+'/'+filename);
    const fs = file.createWriteStream({});
    fs.on('finish', function () {
        console.log(`Message ${filename} successfully written to file.`);
    });
    fs.on('error', function (error) {
        console.warn(`Message ${filename} could not be written to file. Retry will be called. Error: ${error.message}`);
        setTimeout(backupQueue(event, callback), 1000);
    });

    fs.write(Buffer.from(pubsubMessage.data, 'base64').toString());
    fs.end();

    callback();
};`
```

---

EDIT:

I opened an issue on [google-cloud-node](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node/issues/2158) and they reported this as a bug. It should be fixed by next release.